# no tty present and no askpass program specified with `ssh -A`

Tags: server, bash, ssh, tty

I'm trying the following command:

```
ssh -A user@server 'bash -s' < mylocalscript.sh
```

But get the annoying `sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified`
when the script reaches a `sudo`. According to `man ssh`, `-A` is supposed to forward local authentication, so it should be able to use `sudo` on the remote server..

What am I doing wrong/not understanding..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSH authentication and sudo authentication are two different sets of credentials. The `-A` option to the `ssh` command applies to SSH only. It provides the ability to forward your credentials so you can ssh from `server` to another system using your local SSH key.

Unless you have sudo rules allowing you to run commands with no password, it will always need to prompt for your password, either from your shell's terminal or using an askpass program, if so configured. An askpass program is a (typically graphical) helper program that simply prompts for a password securely. To authenticate with sudo remotely, you will have to do one of the two things it is requesting:

- Ensure you have a tty so sudo can securely prompt for your password on the server. This is as easy as logging in with `ssh -t`.
- Tell sudo to prompt for your password using an askpass program with the `-A` option on `sudo` (not to be confused with the `-A` option for `ssh`!). This can be done in your script, for example, with something like:

  ```
  export SUDO_ASKPASS=/usr/lib/openssh/gnome-ssh-askpass
  sudo -A ...
  ```

Note that since you are piping your shell script to the standard input stream of the SSH connection, `sudo` will be unable to securely prompt for a password. If sending the script over the SSH standard input like this is a requirement (instead of just copying the script to the server), then the first option will not work. You will have to either use an askpass helper program or configure the required `sudo` rules to use `NOPASSWD`, if that is an option.

Comment: Option **1** doesn't seem to work, I get `Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.`

Comment: Ah, good catch, thanks for correcting. That's because you are piping the script to standard input, so sudo cannot prompt you for your password over the same channel. So basically you will have to use the askpass helper, or change your sudo permissions to use `NOPASSWD`.

Comment: I had the user in a group `www-data` and that group didn't have `NOPASSWD` but the user did, and this prevented it from working. Seems like both need it, or maybe just the group?

Comment: @Knownasilya, not when I tested it. If a user matches sudo rules for the user name and the group name, then any of them should work. If you `ssh user@server sudo -l` it should list all rules that match. Maybe missing or extra punctuation in `/etc/sudoers`? That trips me up every now and then.

Comment: Don't think so, I used `sudo visudo` which catches errors..

Comment: @Knownasilya  if you have two rules that match the user/machine/command of the sudo rule, then it is the second (later) rule that will be used. as such if you have NOPASSWD, make sure it is after the other one.

Answer (score 1):

Your premise that -A will help sudo is wrong unfortunately. It merely forwards the ssh-agent. You will have to run askpass like the warning suggests.

Also note that `bash -c` is not needed. You can simple pipe in your script with `ssh server < mylocalscript.sh`